# Programmatically process numbers into word form

Tags: numbers, pseudocode

This might be a stupid question and a little embarrassing for me to ask but I really wanna know how I could have done this if I knew what to do that time.

So back in college when I was applying at a company for my internship, they conducted a test through a technical examination. The task was to write a code of any choice of programming language or just a pseudo code for processing inputted integer numbers from 0 up to 9999 and provide its output in worded form.(Ex. 4130 = Four thousand one hundred thirty)

Right now that I am already working I still think about this as I still do not know it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would create a map of pairs with an integer and a string that converts words, such as 
`(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')
                        , (5, 'five'),  (6, 'six'), (7, 'seven'), (8, 'eight'), (9, 'nine'), (10, 'ten'), (11, 'eleven')
                        , (12, 'twelve'), (20, 'twenty'), (30, 'thirty'), (40, 'forty'), (50, 'fifty'), (60, 'sixty'), (70, 'seventy'), (80, 'eighty'), (90, 'ninety')
                        , (100, 'hundred'), (1000, 'thousand')`

I would then parse out the numbers as characters and multiply it based on their place.

e.g. **4**130 = value of 4 == 'four', with a place of [1][0][0][0] = 1000, concatenate 'thousand' based on that lookup, and so on. 
Once you know the exceptions you can create the rest of them easily. This would scale up to 999,999.